# Good introductory book coupling methods

Tags: probability, reference-request, book-recommendation, markov-process, coupling

I am very interested in coupling methods, can you recommend me a good introductory books  on this subject?

Thanks

Comment: [Lectures on the Coupling Method](http://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Coupling-Method-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486421457/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1451419712&sr=8-1&keywords=coupling+method)

Answer (score 3):

I'll suggest "Coupling, stationarity, and regeneration" by Hermann Thorisson. It is both accessible and advanced enough so that you will probably find everything you need. I should also add that this book contains a first part that explain coupling without using measure theory, which might be useful to some readers, before working out the full details of the theory.